# Pandas DF tokenize certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that I has 3 columns. Col 1 is and ID, and Cols 2 and 3 have Text. I want to be able to tokenize Cols 2 and 3, for searching in a task I will do later on.
I have done this code

```
def tokenize_words (words):
    word_new = []
    for word in (words[:][0]):
        word_token = word_tokenize(words)
        if word_token !='':
            word_new.append(word_token)
    return word_new
```

I am unsure on how to call this function that I have defined?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unsure if your function will actually work, the way you call functions on pandas columns is generally by using the Series.apply() method.

```
import pandas as pd

def word_tokenize(text):
    return text.split()

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'col1' : list(range(5)),
    'col2' : ['This is a test string' for x in range(5)]
})

print(df)

    col1    col2
0   0   This is a test string
1   1   This is a test string
2   2   This is a test string
3   3   This is a test string
4   4   This is a test string

df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))

print(df)

    col1    col2
0   0   ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
1   1   ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
2   2   ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
3   3   ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
4   4   ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9811508/tobias-p-g Wondering why you say that my function won't work?

Comment: Well you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, but if your columns contains strings, and you want to tokenize these strings, the way you slince it doesn't make any sense. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, it's generally not really clear what the function is supposed to do, and what your word_tokenize function does :)

Comment: So I read in xml files into a panda df. Cols 2 and 3 are sting text that I would like to word tonenize

Comment: please improve your original post according to the link I described, then it will be much easier to help you.